# Add jQuery into Adobe Brackets HTML Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-brackets

I recently downloaded Adobe Brackets onto my computer, but I soon realized I wasn't able to use jQuery in the same way I had before. The jQuery isn't functioning at all in the program and it is vital to the way the program works.

Website is [tiletap.neocities.org](http://tiletap.neocities.org)

Answer (score 2):

You can use developer tools in the browser to debug problems like this. For example, in Chrome:

1. Open the menu and choose *More Tools > Developer Tools*
2. Select the Console tab
3. Are there any errors listed in red? If so, what do they say? If the error links to a specific line of code, you can click it to go to that code. Often looking at the code and the error message together makes it obvious what's wrong. (And if not, you can post those two pieces of information in your question here so others can help you).
4. Select the Network tab, then reload your page to get fresh information
5. Click the filter icon (it looks like a funnel) and type "jquery"
6. Are any of the network requests in the list shown in red? If so, then the browser was unable to load jQuery – make sure you're using the correct URL. If there are no jQuery items showing up in the list, make sure yous HTML `<script>` tag has the correct syntax.